# Let $f,g:S^5\to S^5$ are degree 2 maps. Then show that we can find a map $\psi:C(g\circ f)\to C(g)$ and find its effect on homology groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Here $C(f)=Cone(f:X\to Y)$ is the pushout of
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>>>C(X)\\
@V{f}VV @VVV\\
Y @>>> C(f)
\end{CD}

And $C(X):=\frac{X\times[0,1]}{X\times 1}$ denotes the cone of $X$.

For notational convenience we denote $f:S^5_a\to S^5_b$ and $g:S^5_b\to S^5_c$. Then we know

$$C(g\circ f)=\frac{S^5_c\sqcup C(S^5_a)}{g\circ f(x)\sim [(x,0)]}$$

First we define the map $\displaystyle{\phi:S^5_c\sqcup C(S^5_a)\to C(g)=\frac{S^5_c\sqcup C(S^5_b)}{g(x)\sim [(x,0)]}}$ by
$$\phi(x)=[x]\ \forall x\in S^5_c$$ and $$\phi([x,t])=[f(x),t]\ \forall [(x,t)]\in C(S^5_a)$$

Then $\phi(g\circ f(x))=[(f(x),0)]=\phi([(x,0)])$. Hence, by the universal property of quotient spaces $\phi$ induces the map
$$\psi:C(g\circ f)\to C(g)$$
Now I have to calvculate the $\psi_*:H_k(C(g\circ f))\to H_k(C(g))$.

I know that as $f,g$ has degree $2$, so $g\circ f$ has $4$. Hence, $$C(g\circ f)\cong M(\Bbb{Z}/4,5)\text{ and } C(g)\cong M(\Bbb{Z}/2,5)$$
where $H_5(M(\Bbb{Z}/n,k))=\Bbb{Z}/n,\ H_0(M(\Bbb{Z}/n,k))=\Bbb{Z}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Can anyone help me to compute $\psi_*:H_k(C(g\circ f))\to H_k(C(g))$ for $k=0,5$? Thanks for help in advance.